# QVariant is not defined when using addAttributes

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

When I try to add a field programmatically with the following code:

```
import os.path
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
legend = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface()
allLayers = legend.layers()
for i in allLayers:
  lyrName = i.name()
  GDBname = str(lyrName)
  print GDBname.split('_', 1)[0]
  lyrProv = i.dataProvider()
  i.startEditing()
  lyrProv.addAttributes( [ QgsField("testName", QVariant.double) ] )
```

I receive an error:

lyrProv.addAttributes( [ QgsField("testName", QVariant.double) ] )
NameError: name 'QVariant' is not defined

Can someone help?

Comment: Just figured it out. I had to change the import statement to:  from PyQt4.QtCore import *

Comment: This question and answer solves the problem of adding attributes as per the pyQGIS cookbook and failing to add  "from PyQt4.QtCore import *" which is NOT specified on that page (or anywhere else that I could find). In that respect this Q/A is very useful.

Comment: I had exactly this issue using QGIS 2.01 on Ubuntu. Same solution also, though I would have preferred not to have to resort to import all.

Comment: Worth noting that a standalone process in QGIS3.X should include the line `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` to solve the problem